# Proving that $\sum \overline{PV_i}^2=\frac{nl^2}{4}\left(1+2\cot^2 \frac{\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: geometry

Given that $P$ is any point on the incircle of a regular $n$-sided polygon with edge length $l$ and vertices $V_1,V_2...V_n$, how do we prove that $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{PV_i}^2=\dfrac{nl^2}{4} \left(1+2\cot^2 \dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$$
?

Here is a figure of what I understand

[image]

I don't even know where to begin with this one.. We want to prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{PV_i}^2$ is independent of the chosen point $P$..

Hints in the right direction and answers appreciated.

Please avoid using vector algebra or complex numbers to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $W_i$ be the midpoint of the segment $\overline{V_iV_{i+1}}$ (where $V_{n+1}=V_1$). Apply the [Apollonius' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem) on the triangle $\triangle PV_iV_{i+1}$ with the midpoint $W_i$. We have
$$\overline{PV_i}^2+\overline{PV_{i+1}}^2=2(\overline{PW_i}^2+\overline{V_iW_i}^2)=2\overline{PW_i}^2+\frac{l^2}{2}$$
Summing this up with all $1\le i\le n$ gives
$$2\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PV_i}^2=2\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PW_i}^2+\frac{n}{2}l^2\tag{1}$$
Now we will show that if $T_1T_2\cdots T_n$ is a regular polygon with a circumcircle of radius $r$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PT_i}^2=2nr^2$ for every point $P$ on the circle.

Without the loss of generality, assume $P$ lie on the arc $T_1T_n$. From the law of cosines, $$\overline{PT_i}^2+\overline{PT_{i+1}}^2=2\overline{PT_i}\cdot\overline{PT_{i+1}}\cos\frac\pi n+(2r\sin\frac\pi n)^2=4\cot\frac\pi n|\triangle PT_iT_{i+1}|+(2r\sin\frac\pi n)^2$$ for all $1\le i\le n-1$. For $i=n$,\begin{align}\overline{PT_1}^2+\overline{PT_{n}}^2&=2\overline{PT_1}\cdot\overline{PT_{n}}\cos\frac{(n-1)\pi }n+(2r\sin\frac{(n-1)\pi} n)^2\\&=-4\cot\frac\pi n|\triangle PT_1T_n|+(2r\sin\frac\pi n)^2\end{align}
Sum this up by $i$ and get \begin{align}2\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PT_i}^2&=4\cot\frac\pi n|T_1T_2T_3\cdots T_n|+4nr^2\sin^2\frac\pi n\\&=4\cot\frac\pi n\sum_{i=1}^n|\triangle OT_iT_{i+1}|+4nr^2\sin^2\frac\pi n\\&=4\cot\frac\pi n\sum_{i=1}^nr\sin\frac\pi nr\cos\frac\pi n+4nr^2\sin^2\frac\pi n\\&=4nr^2\end{align} Therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PT_i}^2=2nr^2$

Now back to the original problem. The $W_1W_2\cdots W_n$ is a regular n-polygon lying on a circle with radius $r=\frac l2\cot\frac\pi n$. So $$\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PW_i}^2=2nr^2=\frac{nl^2}{2}\cot^2\frac\pi n$$ Hence from $(1)$, we get $$\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{PV_i}^2=\frac{nl^2}4(1+2\cot^2\frac\pi n)$$ and we are done.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of the proof. Rescaling, you can assume $l=1$ without loss.
The vertices of the regular polygon are $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n$ where
$V_k$ has coordinates $(\cos(k\frac{2\pi}{n}),\sin(k\frac{2\pi}{n}))$.
Denote by $I_k$ the middle point of the segment $[V_kV_{k+1}]$. Using
the prosthaphaeresis formulas, we obtain

$$I_k\ \Bigg(\cos\bigg(k\frac{2\pi}{n}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}\bigg),
\cos\bigg(k\frac{2\pi}{n}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}\bigg)\Bigg)\tag{1}$$

Since all the $I_k$ are on the incircle, we deduce 
$r=OI_k=|\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{n}\bigg)|$.

If $P(x,y)$ is a point on the incircle, let us put $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $T=\sum_{k=1}^n PV_k^2$. Then :

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
T &=& \sum_{k=1}^n (x-\cos(k\theta))^2+(y-\sin(k\theta))^2 \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^n x^2+y^2-2\cos(k\theta)x-2\sin(k\theta)y+1 \\
&=& n(r^2+1)-2x\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(k\theta)\Bigg)
-2y\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k\theta)\Bigg) \\
\end{array}
$$

Now, each of the sums $C=\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(k\theta)$ and $S=\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k\theta)$ are zero. For $S$, this is easy :
the fact that the sine function is odd suffices. For $C$, this is very easy using complex numbers, and a 
little harder if you won’t use complex numbers (hint : use two different symmetries, according to whether $n$ is even or odd).
So $T=n(r^2+1)$ is indeed independent of $P$. The rest is simple trigonometric manipulation.

Comment: My understanding was that the OP would like to avoid the use of coordinate method (which is essentially the vector algebra).

Comment: However this answer definitely does not deserve a downvote (+1).

Comment: @OL My understanding was different from yours : "Vector algebra" is about using the scalar product and vectors "as numbers", and so does not necessarily include the coordinate method. The OP will tell us himself what he meant ...

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Definitely. Using co-ordinate geometry didn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P \in \mathbb{C}$ and let your regular polygon by the points $R\omega^k = Re^{2\pi i k /n}$ in the complex plane.

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |P - R\omega^k|^2
= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigg( |P|^2 - R(P\omega^{-k} +\overline{P}\omega^k) + R^2 \bigg)
= n \big(|P|^2 + R^2\big)
$$

$P$ is a point on the incircle so we need the radius, $|P| = r = \tfrac{l}{2}\csc \frac{\pi}{n}{n}$.

The radius of the circle in terms of the edge length is: $R = \tfrac{l}{2} \tan \frac{\pi}{n}$.

$\boxed{\sum \overline{PV}^2 = n  \big( \tfrac{l^2}{4} \cot^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n} + \tfrac{l^2}{4}\csc^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n} \big) }$

---

Alterantively we can use [parallel axis theorem](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_19.html).  Your sum is the [moment of inertia](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_19.html) ($I=\sum mr^2$) for unit masses ($m=1$) placed on the vertices $V$.

If your rotation axis were placed at the center of the polygon, the moment of inertia would be $m$ times the radius:

$$I_{CM} = \sum  \overline{OV}^2 = \frac{nl^ 2}{4} \csc^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n}  $$

Moving the center we add the term $md^2$ where $d$ is the distance from the origin to the point $\overline{OP}$ which is the radius of the incircle $|P| = 2l \cot n$

$$ I = I_{CM} + md^2 = \frac{nl^ 2}{4} \csc^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n} + 
 \frac{nl^2 }{4} \cot^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n} = 
 \boxed{\frac{nl^ 2}{4} \big( 1 + 2 \cot^2 \tfrac{\pi}{n} \big)} $$

For discussion of moment of inertia see Feynman Lectures I [Ch 19](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_19.html)